# How to use a for each or iterate through divs?

Tags: jquery

I built my own version of a jquery tab content system. The basic markup is as follows.

```
<div class="row" id="toShow>
    <div> 
        content
    </div>
    <div> 
        content
    </div>
    <div> 
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

The nav goes in another row

```
<div class="row" id="Links>
    <ul>
        <li>link</li><li>link</li><li>link</li><li>link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the js that runs the tab

```
$('.toShow .dslc-modules-area:not(:first)').addClass("hide"); 

$( ".links li" ).click(function() {
    $( ".links li" ).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var identify=$(this).index();
    $(".toShow .dslc-modules-area:not(:eq(identify))").addClass("hide");
    $(".toShow .dslc-modules-area").eq([identify]).removeClass('hide').toggleClass("showme");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".toShow").offset().top + 0}, 800);
```

if I have two accordions on the first one works and am assuming it's an iteration/for each issue? My question is, without having to do links1, links2 etc is there a way to have the code work for every set of accordions? that is to say, for each set of #toShow and #Links run this code?

Comment: `$( ".links li" ).siblings().removeClass('active')` is like running a while loop that increments `i` from `1` to `10` 20 times, only to set its value to `1` right after. Drop `siblings()` and just use `$( ".links li" ).removeClass('active')`

Comment: @DanielBeck Your edit corrected possible mistakes in the author's post that could cause the issue to become non-existent, if not in this case, then in the future. Please avoid non-whitespace changes to code in questions. I rolled back the edit, if you wish to re-apply the grammar corrections, then go ahead.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Given the asker's statement that the first one works I assumed the typos were just transcription errors, but your point is perfectly valid; I'll bear that in mind in the future. Apologies.

Comment: @DanielBeck That could potentially be true, but generally speaking, it's better to ask the OP themselves to fix their code blocks if you think the markup might be off instead of making an educated guess if it was intended or not based on context.

Comment: You're absolutely right @DJDavid98; my bad.  Deedub, there are some missing quotation marks after your ID attributes, and you've mixed up classes and IDs (with different casing) in a couple of spots (`'.links'` and `id="Links` for example).  I don't think these are directly relevant to your question but it may be worth editing.

Comment: sorry that was sloppy on my part. I was just trying to give a sense of the code pattern, it's not the code am using specifically so there were errors.

Answer (score 0):

The main sticking point here is that you need a way to distinguish between the tabs and contents meant for tab set 1, and those for tab set 2, so that clicks on one of them won't affect the other set. `$('.links li')` would match all of the links from both sets, for example, so you'll end up with crosstalk between the tab sets unless you limit your selectors.

Lots of ways to fix that.  Here I'm wrapping each tab set's elements inside a single wrapper element, and modifying your code to act on the contents of each wrapper individually:

```js
/* Init each tabset separately, using '.find' to limit the subsequent
   selector to act only within that node: */
$('.tabset').find('.toShow div:not(:first)').addClass("hide");
$('.tabset').find('.links li:first').addClass("active");

/* Now attach the event handlers to the links, again separately 
   for each tabset: */
$('.tabset').each(function() {
  var tabset = $(this); // so we don't collide with the 'this' inside the click handler below
  tabset.find(".links li").click(function() {
    tabset.find(".links li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var identify = $(this).index();
    tabset.find(".toShow div:not(:eq(identify))").addClass("hide");
    tabset.find(".toShow div").eq([identify]).removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="tabset">
     <div class="row links">
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li><li>link 2</li><li>link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row toShow">
      <div>content 1</div><div>content 2</div><div>content 3</div>
    </div>
</span>

<span class="tabset">
    <div class="row links">
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li><li>link 2</li><li>link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row toShow">
      <div>content 1</div><div>content 2</div><div>content 3</div>
    </div>
</span>
```

(This could be improved by binding a delegated click event to the tabset node itself, i.e. `$('.tabset').on('click','.links li', function() {...});` instead of individual events to each `li`, but that's not the question you were asking.)

If your DOM structure for whatever reason doesn't permit the addition of that wrapper node, you could instead depend on document order (limit each `.links` row to act only on the next sibling `.toShow` row, for example) or by adding a data attribute (or class, or whatever) to each pair (limit each `.links[data-tabset="foo"]` to act only on `.toShow` items which also have `data-tabset="foo"`).  Here's an example using only document order:

```js
/* Init is basically the same as the previous snippet: */
$('.toShow').find('div:not(:first)').addClass("hide");
$('.links').find('li:first').addClass("active");

$('.links li').click(function() {
  /* But here we need to traverse the DOM to find the correct sets
     of links and content blocks to act on.  This looks simpler, but
     is more fragile to document order changes, so I'd really recommend 
     the other approach, or an explicit identifier: */
  var linkRow = $(this).closest('.links');
  var showRow = linkRow.next('.toShow');
  var identify = $(this).index();
  
  // The rest is basically as before:
  linkRow.find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  showRow.find("div:not(:eq(identify))").addClass("hide");
  showRow.find("div").eq([identify]).removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row links">
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li><li>link 2</li><li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row toShow">
  <div>content 1</div><div>content 2</div><div>content 3</div>
</div>

<div class="row links">
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li><li>link 2</li><li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row toShow">
  <div>content 1</div><div>content 2</div><div>content 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a jQuery each function():

See the entry in the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: You can loop through parent tags with each, so through multiple accordions. So the answer is on the documentation page. So you question is not clear if you could not fix it with this info

Comment: the second set of #links interacts with the first set of #toShow rather than the second.

Comment: Link only answers provide very little value to the community. WIthout a practical display of using that method it really does nothing to answer the question

Comment: What if the link contains a display of how to use?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer give some of the (long) history on why link-only answers are discouraged.